# Unclear how to determine if a set of matrices is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I determine whether this set of matrices forms a basis for the linear space of all $2\times 2$ matrices?

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}, B= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, C= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 3 & -2 \end{bmatrix}, D= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ask yourself two questions: "Does it span the space?"  and "Are the matrices linearly independent?"  You need the answer to both questions to be "Yes" to conclude that this set is a basis for the space.

Comment: This example should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857633/finding-the-basis-and-dimension-of-a-subspace-of-the-vector-space-of-2-by-2-matr/2302129#2302129

Answer (score 1):

To form a basis, two things have to be true.

1. There have to be as many of them as the dimension of the space.
2. They have to be linearly independent.

In this case the space has dimension 4 and there are 4 of them, so point 1 is taken care of.  As for the second, use row reduction to try to find a linear dependence.  If there is one, you'll find it.  If not, then it is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer you need to show two things:

First one is obvious. To show that this matrices are linearly independent you can just assume some dependence and write the following:
$$
  \alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C + \delta D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
So you get four equations and solving this system of equations you can show that $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = 0$.